# Detecting collisions in unity without actually applying force to the object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey so i am making a 2d game that is very similar to flappy bird (you jump when tapping the screen). The point of the game is to catch the green squares coming to you.

---

The problem i am encountering is that when my player hits the green square it seems to collide with it (it throws the player in some random direction or even stop into place like it hit a wall) even if on collision the green square is being destroyed.
So whenever the player hits the green square prefab it increments the score and destroys the square but sometimes when i jump right before hitting the square it stops like it collided with it insted of just passing right through.

---

**The player prefab has got a rigidbody component and a 2d square collider.**
**The green square prefab has got only a 2d square collider component attached to it.**

---

I am very new to unity and this is the first game i started developing.
If you need any further information please don't hesitate to ask.

---

[Here is the player's rigidbody and 2d collider settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwpMT.png)

---

[Here is the green square's 2d collider settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9jFb.png)

---

Maybe this picture of the gameplay can help. **Imagine the blue square is the player and the green squares are the points you have to hit the red things are just the enemies that kill you so don't mind them. The player is standing still and the green square prefab have a script attached to it that adds a constant force to them.** Hopefully this made it a lot clearer.

Comment: do green elements need to collide physicaly each other or with somthing else ?

If not, you could use [triggers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

"A collider configured as a Trigger (using the Is Trigger property) does not behave as a solid object and will simply allow other colliders to pass through."

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your GameObjects configuration mainly rigid body and a square collider?

Comment: Ok so to make things a little bit more clear the green things have a constant force applied to them in order to move to the player from the side of the screen. They only interacti with the player not with each other or other gameobjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a trigger on your green Squares. then the bird is allowed to pass true but the square will activate your OnTriggerEnter code in your script.

so what you can try is:

```
    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
            {
            //Run your code here!!!
            //for example
             Rigidbody rb = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
            }
    }
```

this will add a force to your player/bird. but you can run any code in that method.

Comment: Hey  i still don't quite understand the diffrence of OnTriggerEnter and OnCollisionEnter can you please explain this to me. In my code i used OnCollisionEnter.

Comment: @Tudoraster Can you share the code? It's difficult to provide a decent solution to your problem without seeing the code that has the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really useful unity function that will detect when a collider touches another collider.
It is: `void OnCollisionEnter(...)`

You also have to pass in a `Collider` or `Collider2d`. So it will look like:

- `void OnCollisionEnter(Collider col)`
- or `void OnCollisionEnter(Collider2D col)`

Of course you have to have the necessary import statements for unity engine at the top as well.

Answer (score 0):

OnTriggerEnter and OnCollisionEnter run both when the object is hit by a rigidbody. but with OntriggerEnter you can pass thru the object. because it does not get effected by other physics objects. but onCollision usually does unless you freeze it in position.

*side note OnTriggerEnter runs in FixedUpdate, so it is run at the end of each frame*

Comment: Thanks and if i check the is trigger box on the collider it means that i have to use OnTriggerEnter function right?

Comment: yes. if you check isTrigger it runs OnTriggerEnter.

Comment: I recommend using OnTriggerEnter when the object should be static and/or the object is not interactable by physics. like a collider for a checkpoint. but your problem should be fixed with this solution.